# blob.toPDF doesn't format text

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, contentdocument

```
cv.VersionData = blob.toPDF(Stringvalue);
```

is creating a pdf with bold characters, how do I save the format in the same way that I'm passing from JS?

Comment: It uses HTML. Are you using HTML to format the text?

Comment: Looks like in preview mode it doesn't respect the HTML formatting, when I download it everything seems to be working fine.